# iOS L2CAP/GATT- throughput

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt, throughput, l2cap

I'm trying to achieve high throughput over iPhone with my device (using gatt or l2cap).

For L2cap:
I used https://github.com/bluekitchen/CBL2CAPChannel-Demo/blob/master/CBL2CAPChannel-Demo/BKL2CAPClient.m on my iphone, and a test from bluekitchen (le_credit_based_flow_control_server)
for my device.
I received throughput of 18 kilobyte per sec.
It's very low for what I'm trying to achieve
(I used test of bluekitchen from the server side, iphone is client)

For Gatt:
Using LightBlue I checked throughput over GATT and received throughput of 33 kilobyte per sec
which is still low

On Android I got much better results
l2cap - 66 kilobyte per sec
gatt - 63 kilobyte per sec.

Can anybody help with that?

Also
does ios core bluetooth support l2cap over br/edr?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/

Comment: My testing of L2CAP between two iOS devices gives about 20Kb/s

Comment: Thanks. Did you also test Gatt?